# What is the difference between MongoClient and the client object which we get in the callback of MongoClient.connect() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
const debug = require('debug')('mongodb-connect');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
  if (err) return debug(`Unable to connect to the server ${err}`);
  debug('Connected to the server');
  const db = client.db('TodoApp');
  db.collection('Todos').insertOne({
    text: 'Something to do',
    completed: false,
  }, (error, result) => {
    if (err) return debug(`There was a problem while inserting, ${error}`);
    debug(`Data inserted successfully ${JSON.stringify(result.ops, undefined, 2)}`);
  });
  client.close();
});
```

Now in the above code, I've an object of MongoClient and I called MongoClient.connect() method to connect my Node app with my local database server. In my callback I get another client object which I used to perform the database operations. I'm confused between differentiating both objects: MongoClient and client(from the callback)

Answer (score 2):

`MongoClient` is the name of a class that you imported from the `mongodb` package.

`MongoClient.connect()` is a static method of that class. It creates an **actual instance** of `MongoClient` (your `client` object) and passes it to your callback.

You cannot really do much ẁith `MongoClient`, as it is just a representation/a class of an actual client. It is not an instance that you could call any of the methods on.

Only just by calling `MongoClient.connect`, you get an instance of that class that you can actually use to work with your MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but `initialized db object`.

You should look into [this](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html). Mongo team has the well-documented explanation.

1. MongoClient: Use for connecting by URL.
2. mongoClient(client) as a parameter: Will return DB object if the connection would be successful.